# How to validates Rails column with self other column not blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a mode named Exam.

There are some columns in `exames`:

```
:title
:subject_id
:exam_type
```

**I want to know how to implement this:**

```
class Exam < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :subject_id, presence: true, if: :no_exam_type?

  def no_exam_type?
    self.exam_type == ""
  end
end
```

That is to say, I want to create a exam:

```
Exam.create(title: "first exam", exam_type: "something")
```

The `subject_id` must be exist, when `exam_type` is blank, such as `exam_type=""` or just do:

```
Exam.create(title: "first exam", subject_id: 3)
```

because `exam_type` has a default blank value.

But the `subject_id` doesn't necessary provide, when `exam_type` not blank, such as `exam_type="something"`.

```
    Exam.create(title: "first exam", exam_type: "something", subject_id: 3)
```

I test it, but no lucky.

How to do that? Thanks appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 5 `belongs_to` associations default to `optional: false`. Which means that the model will automatically validate the presence of the association.

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :other_thing
end

Thing.create!
# => ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: other_thing can't be blank
```

So you need to set the association as optional and make sure the column is nullable.

```
class Exam < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subject, optional: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :subject_id, presence: true, if: :no_exam_type?

  def no_exam_type?
    !self.exam_type.present?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this.

```
validates :subject_id, presence: true, :if => exam_type.blank?
```

you can refer the doc [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-string-with-if-and-unless) to suite your requirement

Answer (score -1):

use **validates_presence_of** instead.

```
validates_presence_of :subject_id, if: :no_exam_type?
def no_exam_type?
    self.exam_type.nil?
end
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't worked.  When I run `Exam.create!(title: "title test", exam_type: "test")` from rails console, there are a error `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:` .